# Washing Machine pauses several times while working

Tags: washing-machine

I have a Samsung 6.5kg washing machine (WA65H4300HA). I have been using it for about 6 years without any issues. But now, sometimes, while the machine is running, it pauses for 5 - 20 minutes several times.
After pausing, it starts again on it's own from where it was. Also all buttons except power button don't work sometimes and water level always automatically sets to level 2 no matter how much clothes in the machine (this can be changed manually by pressing the water level button though). Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible you have enabled some sort of "pre-soak" mode?  I know some units have this feature.

Comment: Have you reviewed the manual (in paper or internet form) to follow the trouble shooting tips there?

Comment: It may be time to get a service tech repair it as nothing appears to work properly. You could consider purchasing another machine. If it were me I would replace it and save the cost of a service call. Asela, just a thought, is it possibly you have lightning damage, have other electronic devices failed or just the washer.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, I will try your suggestions. Also the machine works perfectly fine sometimes (except water level setting), so I am not sure what's really going on.